# subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'buildozer android debug' returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, github, kivy, github-actions, buildozer

I'm trying to build a kivy apk using GitHub Actions. My `buildozer.spec`, `main.py`, `build.yml` - everything is ok. And everything was working 3 months ago with these same file, but now it’s not working. I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/action/entrypoint.py", line 159, in <module>
    main()
  File "/action/entrypoint.py", line 27, in main
    run_command(env["INPUT_COMMAND"])
  File "/action/entrypoint.py", line 135, in run_command
    retcode = subprocess.check_call(command, shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'buildozer android debug' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```